# Frequency spectrum of an amplitude modulated signal

Tags: frequency-spectrum, modulation

I am talking about a DSB- Suppressed Carrier amplitude modulation.
Let message signal be $m(t)=A_m \cos{\omega_c t}$ and carrier signal be $c(t)=A_c \cos{\omega_m t}$
Then the amplitude modulated signal is 
$$s(t)=m(t)c(t)$$
$$s(t)=A_c A_m \cos{\omega_c t} \cos{\omega_m t}$$
$$s(t)=\frac{A_c A_m}{2} \{\cos{(\omega_c+\omega_m) t} + \cos{(\omega_c-\omega_m) t}\} \tag3$$
In frequency domain $s(t)$ is[image]

From eq **3** it is visible that two frequency components $\omega_c+\omega_m$ , $\omega_c-\omega_m$ are present.
**Then in frequency domain $S(\omega)$ why isn't there an impulse at these locations ?** (and at their negative frequencies, of course)

Comment: Your figure shows a modulated message signal with a triangular spectrum, not a sinusoidal message signal as given by your formula for $m(t)$. So the equation for $m(t)$ and the figure don't fit together.

Comment: the figure is of  $s(t)$

Comment: I understand that, but still, the corresponding message signal has a triangular spectrum. The spectrum of $m(t)$ is that triangle centered at $\omega=0$.

Comment: Well, the figure is supposed to be of $S(\omega)$, but it is not the Fourier transform of $s(t)$ that you've written in the question.

Comment: @MattL. ok. for a sinusoidal signal $m(t)$ how does its spectrum become a triangle. isn't it 2 impulses.

Comment: That's the point: the figure does not show the spectrum for a sinusoidal message, but for a message with a triangular spectrum.

Comment: @MattL. many books are using this spectrum for explaining DSB,SSB

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the spectrum in the figure, it's just not the spectrum for DSB of a *sinusoidal* message signal. But of course it can be used to explain DSB. The spectrum of DSB with a sinusoidal message signal is given in Peter K.'s answer below.

Answer (score 1):

With $s$, $m$, and $c$ as you display, then the diagram of $S(\omega)$ is incorrect.  If it were, the spectrum of $m$ would be a triangle centered at zero frequency, which it is not.

$$
S(\omega) = \frac{A_cA_m}{4} \left[\\
\delta\left(\omega - (\omega_c + \omega_m)\right)\\
+ \delta\left(\omega - (\omega_c - \omega_m)\right)\\
+ \delta\left(\omega - (-\omega_c - \omega_m)\right)\\
+ \delta\left(\omega - (-\omega_c + \omega_m)\right)\\
\right]$$